# sql: no rows in result set

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, golang

Есть таблица такого формата:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (textt text, ip varchar(22), uid varchar(128));
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON test (uid);
```

И есть код для работы с БД:

```
var db_uid string
err = db.QueryRows("INSERT INTO test (textt, ip, uid) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) ON CONFLICT (uid) DO NOTHING", "hello", "192.168.0.1", curr_uid).Scan(&db_uid)
sreq, err := db.Exec("UPDATE test SET uid = ($1), ip = ($2), textt = ($3) WHERE uid = ($4)", curr_uid, "192.168.1.1", "goodbye", db_uid)
```

Если я вставлю вставку `RETURNING (uid)` к `INSERT`запросу:

```
INSERT INTO test (textt, ip, uid) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING (uid) ON CONFLICT (uid) DO NOTHING;
```

у меня будет синтаксическая ошибка, но также я понимаю что `QueryRow` должно вернуть какое-то значение, но как вернуть конкретное значение `uid`, а не `textt` или `ip` я не знаю. При этом всем вылетает ошибка `sql: no rows in result set`, а вылетает из-за того что я должен был вернуть строку, но вернуть строку я не могу ибо `RETURNING uid` конфликтует с `ON CONFLICT`. Как быть господа?

Answer (score 4):

Согласно [документации](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html) *returning* пишется после *on conflict*.

```
insert into test(a,b) values(1,2) on conflict do nothing returning a;
```

Отработает. Но вренет *a* только если insert произошел, если же был конфликт, то запрос ничего не вернет и возникнет та же "sql: no rows in result set". Что бы он вернул значение и в случае если такая запись в таблице уже есть, то надо что бы произошел update, например заменить колонку на свое собственное значение.

```
insert into test(a,b) values(1,2) on conflict(a) do update set a=test.a returning (a)
```

И запрос разумеется возвращает именно те колонки, которые были перечислены в *returning* так что вы получите именно то что сами укажете, а не какие то другие поля.

P.S. хотя я не совсем понял, зачем вы получаете uid при insert и тут же пытаетесь сделать update этой записи, гораздо проще все выполнить в одном запросе, что то вроде:

```
db.Exec("INSERT INTO test (textt, ip, uid) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) ON CONFLICT (uid) UPDATE SET ip = EXCLUDED.ip, textt = EXCLUDED.textt", "hello", "192.168.0.1", curr_uid)
```

Специальная таблица `EXCLUDED` в выражении обозначает указанные в фразе *values* значения.

Comment: UPDATE я делал потому что мне ПЕРЕД UPDATE нужно было получить значение UID, получить значение и сделать UPDATE в 1 запросе я не могу поэтому я и сделал 2 запроса.

Comment: @tramway Но судя по запросу он вернет тот же самый id, что и был изначально. Вы же пишите `on conflict(uid)` т.е. если запись с таким uid уже есть (а если нет, она будет вставлена) вернуть `returning (uid)` опять же uid. Значит тот uid который она вернет заведомо равен тому, который был в curr_uid. А это означает, что update будет менять ту же самую запись, которую вы только что вставляли

Comment: спасибо, действительно что-то и не подумал... теперь это осознал с вашим объяснением)